# Is there any way to re-enable a disabled checkbox on click?

Tags: gwt

I would like to allow my users to re-enable a disabled checkbox on click. I tried to attach an onClickHandler to my checkbox but since it's disabled, it doesn't see to catch that event:

```
checkbox.onClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Did I miss something? Or would I need to write my own checkbox that extends from CheckBox to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting the CheckBox inside a FocusPanel, or similar. That way when the checkbox is disabled the click event will fall through to the FocusPanel, which can enable the checkbox for you. You might like to put `event.stopPropagation()` in the checkbox click handler to stop the focus panel click handler from being called when the checkbox is enabled.

I haven't tested this but I'm confident it will work. Be careful though. I'd recommend providing another means besides for enabling the checkbox, since a good number of your users won't understand that clicking on a disabled checkbox is going to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but I ran into a similar problem trying to add a tooltip to a disabled button to tell the user why it was disabled but tooltips don't show for disabled items. I had to put the button inside a container and put the tooltip on the container.

Answer (score 0):

On GWT 2.2 the CheckBox Widget:

```
 CheckBox check= new CheckBox();
               check.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {    
                              if(((CheckBox) event.getSource()).getValue()){                                     
                                  //is Checked
                              }else{
                                  //unChecked
                              }


                          }
                        });
```